# Inserir video no HTML depois de 10 segundos usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Pessoal preciso inserir um vídeo no meu HTML depois de 5 segundos utilizando JavaScript, antes de 5 segundos o vídeo não é exibido. Cheguei a colocar o video na página usando Javascript porém tentei utilizar a função SetTimeOut mas sem Exito. Podem me dar dicas de como chegar ao resultado esperado ? Abaixo segue meu código parcial.

HTML

```
< video id="newvideo" autoplay style="position: absolute; width: 480px;height: 270px; z-index: 2; top: 37px;left: 800px;cursor: pointer;">
  </video>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementById("newvideo");

    video.src="video-maxi.mp4";

    video.onmouseover=function(){
      video.volume=1;
      console.log('mouseover')
    } / Ativar som com MouseOver

    video.onmouseout=function(){
      video.volume=0;
      console.log('mouseout');
    } / Desativar som MouseOut
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/video-depois-de-10-segundos.htm)

CSS

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
.show{
    display:block;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
    window.onload=function()
{
    setTimeout(func1, 10000); 

};
function func1()
{
    document.getElementById("video").className="show";
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="video" class="hide">

<video controls id="newvideo" autostart style="position: absolute; width: 480px;height: 270px; z-index: 2; top: 37px;left: 800px;cursor: pointer;">
  <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>
```

> Em javascript, um timeout é uma quantidade de tempo  (em milissegundos) antes que uma expressão indicada seja avaliada. Um timeout não é uma espera ou atraso no script, mas um meio de dizer ao javascript para segurar a execução de uma instrução ou função por uma quantidade de tempo desejada.

Na expressão  `setTimeout(func1, 10000);`  a função  `func1` é executada após o esgotamento do tempo limite de 10000 milissegundos.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método `setTimeout`.

```js
function mostrar() {
  document.getElementById("newvideo").style.visibility = "visible";
};

setTimeout("mostrar()", 5000); // Depois de 5 segundos
```

```html
<div id="newvideo" style="visibility: hidden">Mostre Div depois de 5 segundos</div>
```

Adapte o `html` de acordo com a sua necessidade, substituindo a tag `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda rapaziada,me ajudaram demais. Usei os conceitos das duas respostas e cheguei ao resultado esperado. Abaixo segue o código final.

```js
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {var video=document.getElementById("video").style.display = "block";}, 5000);
</script>
```

```html
 <video id="video" src="video-maxi.mp4" autoplay style="position: absolute; width: 480px;height: 270px; z-index: 2; top: 37px;left: 800px;cursor: pointer; display: none;"> </video>
```